# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ax^3+bx^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: definite-integrals

Is there a closed form for $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{ax^3+bx^2}\,\mathrm{d}x $$?

Comment: no need for a closed form because the definite integral is not convergent anyways (supposing $a$ not null).

Comment: @OJB I tried it with WolframAlpha, and even with extra computational time it still timed out, so it's unlikely that there's a simple closed form expression.

Comment: I assume $b \le 0$ as well. It will be convergent but finding a closed form is something else...

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan So? This is clearly beyond WA. I'm 99.99%  sure a closed form exists for this.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty e^{-x^n}dx=\Gamma\Big(1+\tfrac1n\Big)$

Comment: One can always Taylor expand $e^{bx^2}$, integrate the expression term by term and turn the integral into a sum of 3 generalized hypergeometric functions. I think it is a sum of 3 $_2F_2$.

Comment: @OJB What makes you so sure?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I found this on wiki https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/c/3/cc3a9fca8785f9c913757462a05cee87.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a<0$, and changing variable $y = (-a x^3)$:
$$
   \int_0^\infty \exp(a x^3 + b x^2) \mathrm{d}x = \alpha\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-y + \beta y^{2/3} \right) y^{-2/3} \mathrm{d}y
$$
where $\alpha = 1/\left(3 (-a)^{1/3}\right)$ and $\beta = b (-a)^{-2/3}$.

Now, using $y^{-2/3} \exp\left(\beta y^{2/3}\right) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{1}{m!} \beta^{m} y^{2 (m-1)/3}$, and interchanging the order summation and integration as warranted by Tonelli theorem:
$$
 \int_0^\infty \exp\left(-y + \beta y^{2/3} \right) y^{-2/3} \mathrm{d}y = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\beta^m}{m!} \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-y} y^{2 (m-1)/3} \mathrm{d}y = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{\beta^m}{m!} \Gamma\left(\frac{2m}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\right)
$$
Using duplication and triplication formulae for $\Gamma$-function
$$
    \Gamma(2x) = \frac{2^{2x}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma(x) \Gamma\left(x+\tfrac{1}{2}\right) \quad \Gamma(3x) = \frac{3^{3x}}{2 \sqrt{3} \pi} \Gamma(x)  \Gamma\left(x+\tfrac{1}{3}\right)   \Gamma\left(x+\tfrac{2}{3}\right) 
$$
we can rewrite the summand:
$$
   \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2m}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\right)}{m!}  =  \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{2m}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\right)}{\Gamma(m+1)}  = \frac{2^{1/3} \sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{3}} \left(\frac{2^{2/3}}{3}\right)^m \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{3} + \frac{1}{6}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{m}{3} + 1\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{m}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\right) }
$$
It now suffices to split the sum 
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty g(m) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty g(3k) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty g(3k+1) + \sum_{k=0}^\infty g(3k+2)
$$
and write the answer in terms of hypergeometric functions:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  \int_0^\infty \exp(a x^3 + b x^2) \mathrm{d}x &=& \tilde{\alpha} \frac{\Gamma(1/6)}{\Gamma(1/3)} \cdot {}_1F_1\left(\tfrac{1}{6}; \tfrac{1}{3}; \left(2^{2/3} \frac{\beta}{3}\right)^3 \right) \\
 &+& \tilde{\alpha} \cdot  \frac{2^{2/3} \beta}{3} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(2/3)\Gamma(4/3)} \cdot {}_2F_2\left(1, \tfrac{1}{2}; \tfrac{2}{3},\tfrac{4}{3}; \left(2^{2/3} \frac{\beta}{3}\right)^3 \right) \\
 &+& \tilde{\alpha} \cdot  \left(\frac{2^{2/3} \beta}{3}\right)^2 \cdot \frac{\Gamma(5/6)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(5/3)} \cdot {}_1F_1\left(\tfrac{5}{6}; \tfrac{5}{3}; \left(2^{2/3} \frac{\beta}{3}\right)^3 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $\tilde{\alpha} = \frac{2^{1/3} \sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{3}}\alpha $

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what WolframAlpha gives me, just for $a=-1$:

$$\begin{align*}
\int^\infty_0 e^{-x^3+bx^2}\,dx=-\frac1{27}b\,\left(2\sqrt{3}\pi e^{\tfrac{2b^3}{27}}\left(I_{-\frac13}\left(-\dfrac{2b^3}{27}\right)+I_{\frac13}\left(-\dfrac{2b^3}{27}\right)\right)-9_2F_2\left(\dfrac{1}{2},1;\dfrac23,\dfrac43;\dfrac{4b^3}{27}\right)\right)\,\,\,\\\color{grey}{\text{ for }}\,\operatorname{Re}(b)<0
\end{align*}
$$

It's expressed using Bessel functions and hypergeometric functions, and WolframAlpha was just barely able to compute it with extra computational time. So just imagine how complicated an expression you'd have in the general case.

Comment: A simple substitution, with $x=a^{1/3}y$, and a different $b$, will give the general case